# Trying to add a WHERE Clause to Mysql Query

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to add a where clause here:

```
select `submission_id`, 
       max(case when `key` = 'id_usuario' then value end) as user,
       max(case when `key` = 'date_atualizado' then value end) as Data,
       max(case when `key` = 'peso' then value end) as Peso
from wp_e_submissions_values
group by `submission_id`
```

It is working fine! but I neet to add `WHERE 'user' = 1`

```
select `submission_id`, 
       max(case when `key` = 'id_usuario' then value end) as user,
       max(case when `key` = 'date_atualizado' then value end) as Data,
       max(case when `key` = 'peso' then value end) as Peso
from wp_e_submissions_values
WHERE 'user' = 1
group by `submission_id`
```

I added after FROM ... but it wont work.
I'm getting this error:

```
Attention: #1292 Truncated wrong DOUBLE value: 'user'
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: Use `WHERE user = 1` _without_ the single quotes.  This is a typo error.

Comment: Doens't work, I'm getting: Attention: #1292 Truncated wrong DOUBLE value: 'user'

Comment: You're all looking at it wrong, you can't use aliases in WHERE clauses guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upon reading your question more closely, it looks like the assertion on `user` should be happening in a `HAVING` clause rather than a `WHERE` clause.

```sql
SELECT
    submission_id,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'id_usuario' THEN value END) AS user,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'date_atualizado' THEN value END) AS Data,
    MAX(CASE WHEN `key` = 'peso' THEN value END) AS Peso
FROM wp_e_submissions_values
GROUP BY submission_id
HAVING user = 1;
```